# How to change label font size and color of y axis label in C3.js

Tags: angular, c3.js

i am using this in my CSS but this seems it's not working. i am using c3 with angular 4. Please, can anyone suggest how to make it work? Thanks in advance.

```
.c3-axis-y-label{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:30px;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use d3 select option and add styling to the c3-axis labels

```
d3.select(".c3-axis-y-label")
  .style("font-weight", "bold")
  .style("font-size", "30px");
```